# Microsoft SQLServer driver datasource have password empty

Tags: java, sql-server, datasource

I'm working on a Java project that uses jetty to run on local a webservice that access some databases. We was using jtds to access SQLServer databases, but now **we need to work with DATETIME2 fields** and this **enforce us to use Microsft SQLServer driver** instead of jtds.

So, before setting all to use it, and running OK on some junit test that creates directly Connection objects using these driver, when we try the main app, we get in trouble.
We have a jetty-env.xml like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Call class="org.mortbay.log.Log" name="warn">
        <Arg>executing jetty-env.xml</Arg>
    </Call>

    <New id="DATABASE" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource">
        <Arg>jdbc/DATABASE</Arg>
        <Arg>

            <!--  Servidor SQLserver -->
            <New class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
                <Set name="User">username</Set>
                <Set name="Password">password</Set>
                <Set name="DatabaseName">databasename</Set> 
                <Set name="ServerName">servername</Set> 
                <Set name="PortNumber">portnumber</Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>
</Configure>
```

But when I launch the app with Jetty on Eclipse, I get a SQLException saying that can't log with the username. Setting a breakpoint and debuging, I saw that when the Java code gets the Datasource from context, it not have a password!!!

```
String dsName = props.getProperty ("hibernate.connection.datasource"); // "java:comp/env/jdbc/DATABASE"
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
SQLServerDataSource sqlds = (SQLServerDataSource) ctx.lookup (dsName);
//sqlds.setPassword ("passoword");
DataSource ds = (DataSource) sqlds;
```

If I uncomment the sqlds.setPassword line, it conencts ok to the database. So by a unknow reason, the SQLServerDataSource isn't not getting the password from jetty. I try to use different

Any clue of wtf is happening here ?

PD: We are using Jetty 6 with an old customized version of jetty-run-jetty plugin that auto apply maven overlays. So changing jetty version not is an option at this moment.

edit: added dsnames string

Comment: For context lookup what dsName you are using ? Is this datasource is created by you or its premade ?

Comment: I think that could be build by hibernate ? But I not sure... huge old codebase (jaja! Java 1.4/5 !) that predates me and I can't find were is being generated the Datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, reading Jetty documentation, I see that is Jetty who is generating the DataSource object : https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/JNDI#Configuring_DataSources

> To lookup your DataSource in your servlet/filter/etc.:
>
> import javax.naming.InitialContext;
>   import javax.sql.DataSource;
>
> InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
>   DataSource myDS = DataSource)ic.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/myds");

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need to use the MS driver you should either:

1. Set the password yourself after reference lookup as you did in your first example.
2. Use a Connection pool like Tomcat Pool, Apache Pool or Spring's DriverMnagerConnecionPool and configure them to use the MS driver.

The problem is that the MS SQLServerDataSource implements Referenceable and when asked for its reference by the JNDI environment it does not supply its password parameter. This is hardcoded in the drivers code.
So when the datasource is reconstructed form the reference the password is not there any more.